# Is It Possible to take the Backup of AKS Cluster?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-aks

Here, Actually we are running the Application in AKS Cluster and store the Application related data  we are using the PV&PVC concept we need the backup of the data and has to store in Azure container so is it possible It need a suggestions and best approaches.

Comment: @Imrankhan-MT - please stop spamming people with requests to accept and upvote your answers here and on other questions. Plus, you're posting an answer to a very broad, opinion-soliciting question that's off-topic as written.

Answer (score 1):

You can backup and restore your Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster's persistent volumes in a variety of methods. I would suggest you to use  [**Velero**](https://velero.io/docs/v1.9/) so that you will not loss anything, in case of unintentional deletion or other possible failures.

Please use this article [Azure Kubernetes Services (AKS). Backup/Restore your AKS data with Velero](https://sysadminas.eu/Part-3-AKS/) by ***Andrej Trusevic*** follow accordingly.

- Install velero
- After successfully script execution Velero will be created in your cluster
- Stateless application backup & restore once backup is completed you can be able to see your backup files in the storage account blob container

For Reference:
[Secure and back up your data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/operator-best-practices-storage#secure-and-back-up-your-data)

Comment: Thanks for your quick response so now i am able to take the backup using aks cluster to azure container so i want to take backup using aks cluster to aws s3 or to local is it possible let we know if any possibilityes.

Comment: Yes using velero it is possible, please check this [reference](https://www.lisenet.com/2022/backup-kubernetes-cluster-resources-to-aws-s3-with-velero/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it is possible now for backup AKS cluster using native Azure Backup.

Azure Backup now allows you to back up AKS clusters (cluster resources and persistent volumes attached to the cluster) using a backup extension, which must be installed in the cluster. Backup vault communicates with the cluster via this Backup Extension to perform backup and restore operations.

See details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/azure-kubernetes-service-cluster-restore